# Azure Data Factory Excel read via HTTP fails

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

I am looking to import data form a [publicly available Excel sheet](https://www.environment.gov.au/system/files/resources/79ce6b96-ddb8-4957-87ea-2bf98f89c567/files/abs-waste-data-export-australia-19-20.xlsx) into ADF. I have set up the dataset using an HTTP linked service (see first screenshot), with AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime. However, when I attempt to preview the data, I get an error suggestion that the source file is not in the correct format (second screenshot).

I'm wondering if I may have something set incorrectly in my configuration?

[image: ADF Excel http dataset]

[image: Data factory error message code 21352]

Answer (score 0):

> `.xls` format is not supported while using HTTP.

Since, the API downloads file you can't preview data. You can load file to blob or Azure Datalake Storage using copy activity and then on top of that file have a dataset to preview.

The workaround is to save your `.xlsx` file as a `.csv` file because Azure Data Factory does not support reading `.xlsx` files explicitly for HTTP connectors.

Furthermore, there is no need to convert the.xlsx file to.csv if you only want to copy it; simply select the Binary Copy option.

Here, is a similar discussion where the MS-FTE has confirmed with Product Team that's its not supported yet for HTTP Connector.

Please submit a proposal in the QnA [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) to allow this functionality in future versions, which will be actively monitored by the data factory product team and evaluated for adoption.

Please check the issue at QnA Thread- [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114123/azure-data-factory-excel-connector-unable-to-read.html).